# Date parse exception EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy in few cases

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I am using this format to parse:

```
SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH)
```

However in few minor cases, the date not parsed.

Parsing error

```
Mon Jul 12 13:42:07 GMT+1 2021
Sat Jul 17 09:20:27 IST 2021
```

And successful parsing for the following:

```
Sun Oct 11 12:56:41 GMT+05:30 2020
Fri Aug 20 03:33:16 CST 2021
```

Comment: The timezone offset `+1` is invalid, it has to be something like `+01:00`. Check the format definition on https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#timezone

Comment: I can only partly reproduce. `Mon Jul 12 13:42:07 GMT+1 2021` fails on my Java 11 too, but `Sat Jul 17 09:20:27 IST 2021` is parsed fine (not sure whether the result is as expected, though).

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`. That class is notoriously troublesome and long outdated. Instead use `ZonedDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: How do you expect `IST` to be interpreted? Irish Summer Time, Israel Standard Time, India Standard Time or something else? And `CST`? Central Standard Time, Cuba Standard Time, China Standard Time, …?

Comment: The date string was created by using `Calendar.getInstance().time.toString()`

Comment: Interesting. I haven’t found a way of getting that to produce `GMT+1`. You have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### java.time

I recommend that you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date and time work. Parsing all four of your strings is a bit of challenge alright. The following formatter works.

```
// Substitute your own set of preferred zones here
private static final Set<ZoneId> PREFERRED_ZONES
        = Set.of(ZoneId.of("Atlantic/Reykjavik"), ZoneId.of("America/Havana"));
private static final DateTimeFormatter PARSER = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss [O][")
        .appendZoneText(TextStyle.SHORT, PREFERRED_ZONES)
        .appendPattern("] yyyy")
        .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Trying it out:

```
    String[] strings = {
            "Mon Jul 12 13:42:07 GMT+1 2021",
            "Sat Jul 17 09:20:27 IST 2021",
            "Sun Oct 11 12:56:41 GMT+05:30 2020",
            "Fri Aug 20 03:33:16 CST 2021"
    };

    for (String string : strings) {
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(string, PARSER);
        System.out.println(zdt);
    }
```

Output is:

> ```
> 2021-07-12T13:42:07+01:00
> 2021-07-17T09:20:27Z[Atlantic/Reykjavik]
> 2020-10-11T12:56:41+05:30
> 2021-08-20T03:33:16-04:00[America/Havana]
> ```

While `IST`, `GMT+05:30` and `CST` can be parsed as time zone abbreviations, `GMT+1` cannot. So I am instructing my formatter to parse a *localized offset* if it can. Pattern letter `O` parses `GMT+1` in English (and most other locales). And then to try to parse a time zone abbreviation. The square brackets in the format pattern strings denote optional parts.

Next challenge was that `IST` and `CST` like many time zone abbreviations are ambiguous. So I am also giving the formatter a set of preferred time zones to use to solve the ambiguities. You need to decide which time zones you want those abbreviations to denote, and supply a corresponding set of `ZonedId` objects.

Comment: Alright...The reason why I edited is probably, OP is looking for `Asia/Kolkata` which is GMT+05:30.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash I agree. The presence of `GMT+05:30` in the list suggests that.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash On the other hand Irish Summer Time is at GMT+1, and Ireland does use summer time (DST) in July. So the presence of `GMT+1` may also suggest that Europe/Dublin was sought after. The OP *will have to decide themselves*.